# How do I restrict a content type to a subset of vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical general taxonomy vocabulary called tags. Some of the terms are only relevant to particular content types; e.g., the "Apples" content type might have a sub-tree in the vocabulary with *Cox*, *Granny Smith*, and the "Oranges" content type might have *Seville* in its vocabulary sub-tree.
When editing an *Apple* node, I don't want users to be able to select *Seville* as this doesn't make sense.

I have put the terms into one vocabulary because other content types (e.g. blog articles) might want to tag against any of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree together with views will handle this for you. You will need to set up different views for each content type and then use term_reference_tree together with that view on each content type. As quoted from the module:

> If you want to filter by a view, make sure the view includes the
>   taxonomy term ID, and that the items per page is set to unlimited, as
>   the widget will only display the items from the first page of results.

Summarised module usage for reference:

1. Create a view to filter for the terms you want.

   - Choose Taxonomy for the content, and work on the *Master* display (not *Page* or *Block*)
   - Add the *Name* field
   - Add the *Taxonomy term: Term ID* field BUT check the "exclude from display" option.
   - Turn off the pager
   - For this specific case, add relationship: *Parent term*; create *OR* group in *filter*: (vocab=tags && (parent.tid={Apples's tid} || tid={Apples's tid}). This gives the *Apples* term itself and all its child terms.
   - Possibly needed if view does not work for non-admin users: change the  *Disable SQL Rewriting* option under *Query settings*, but beware that means there is zero access checks on your view.
2. Apply the view to the Term Reference field.

   - Go to the content type fields page.
   - On the Term Reference field in question, click the *Edit* link at the end of the row. You can now see the "Filter by view" option.  (If not, your view is wrong). Choose your view and save these options.
   - Now click the link to change the widget: choose Term Reference Tree.

Comment: Thanks for pointer. I've installed, set the widget, made a view for the tags that I want, but can't for life of me find how to "filter by a view". Is there a UI for this?

Comment: You add your new field > term reference > term ref tree. Choose your vocab. Now you should reach the main settings page where you will have a "Filter by view" option. If you dont then you dont have a taxonomy based view set up yet. To do so, go to views > add view. Remove page checkbox, change content to taxonomy terms and continue and edit. Add taxonomy term ID to the fields, change pager to display all items, then add a filter based on the taxonomy terms you want included for that content type. Save and then go back to the field settings and you should now be able to select the view.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the *Widget* settings not the *Field* settings. I've been able to select my view but now there's no tags at all(!) despite the view's Master display clearly returning the correct tids. I've tried *only* returning tids; I've tried returning tids *and* other fields; I've tried making sure the parent (*Apples*) tid is included. But still, zero tags listed as editable. The view doesn't have contextual filters or anything fancy like that. So near...yet so far!

Comment: For fields have Taxonomy term: Name AND Taxonomy term: Term ID BUT exclude Term ID from display. Then, in filters have a Vocab filter and filter on the same Vocab AND Taxonomy term: Name (=Apples) filter. This is working perfect on my dev box.

Comment: Thanks *so* much! Almost there. So: I do as you said, hide the tid field. Yes! big step forward. But I needed more voodo: add relationship:parent term; create OR group in filter: (vocab=tags && (parent.tid={Apples's tid} || tid={Apples's tid}). So I have Apples and all child terms. **Finally** it shows up as expected. **But for user 1 only.** Other users still see nothing. I've removed access restriction from the view (was only view published content anyway); cleared caches; still nothing.

Comment: Try getting rid of "Disable SQL Rewriting" under query settings, but beware that means there is zero access checks on your view then.

Comment: You, sir/madam, are a genius. **Finally it works**. Thank you very much for your rather extended support :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2249/discussion-between-artfulrobot-and-7wonders)